# Pentaho Get data via http GET or POST request

Tags: pentaho

I have a nodejs server that uses tds to connect to a sqlserver database and returns the requested query in xml or json format.

The request would be in http and include the sql query i.e.

```
Select * from customers
```

The node server works fine, but I now want to connect to this from Pentaho and have been trying to figure out how I can do this.

is this possible and if so how ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CTools, you can use an AjaxRequestComponent or directly in jquery with $.ajax